# MVC 3 - Additional View Data not appearing in Editor For template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my view, I have a statement like this:

```
<li>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeEnum, "Enum", new { ShowDefaultText = false })</li>
```

I have a Enum (SomeEnum) and I have a editor for template for enums.  In my editor for template I'm trying to check the ViewData object for the anonymous class I passed it.  According to he Html.EditorFor documentation, the third parameter is additional view data that will be with the ViewDataDictionary object.

However, in my template when looking at the ViewData class, I don't see the anonymous class/property in it.  Am I doing something wrong, am I looking at the wrong object in my editor for template?

Comment: I also find that whatever I send as `additionalViewData` does not end up in the ViewDataDictionary in the view. Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 9):

Use the following ViewData syntax

```
@{
    var boolValue = Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["ShowDefaultText"]);
 }

 @if (!boolValue)
 {
     ...............
 }
```